# Wizard buttons missing

Tags: qt, frameworks, installation

I managed to get QT installer running on my machine.

On my machine I used:

1. The online installer for Windows for QT ([QTCreator 4.5.1 and QT5.10.1](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5))
2. [QtInstallerFramework-win-x86.exe](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt-installer-framework/3.0.6/QtInstallerFramework-win-x86.exe)

So I started to modify the online example and it's running fine on my machine but when I tried it on a server PC (where QT isn't installed) the buttons in the wizard are missing.

What is the problem?

Comment: I assume it's all about Windows, as far as you don't cread a deb package. Could it be that you forgot to deploy some Qt dlls? Are _all_ of the buttons missing or just some?

Comment: Hi, so it´s a WindowsServer, maybe it´s something about the Server configurations..On normal Windows 10 Computers (without QT being installed, it runs fine).


For Building i used the provided creator, like mentioned here: https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-online-example.html
Do you mean statically bulid QT or statically bulid the insallter helps? I read something about it, but don´t have a glue how to do it..

Comment: And so far all the Buttons are missing, expect the small close button in the upper Right Corner. but this one i can´t hit.